# Solve $\begin{cases}x^2+y^4=20\\x^4+y^2=20\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Solve $$\begin{cases}x^2+y^4=20\\x^4+y^2=20\end{cases}.$$ I was thinking about letting $x^2=u,y^2=v.$ Then we will have $$\begin{cases}u+v^2=20\Rightarrow u=20-v^2\\u^2+v=20\end{cases}.$$ If we substitute $u=20-v^2$ into the second equation, we will get $$v^4-40v^2+v+380=0$$ which I can't solve because we haven't studied any methods for solving equations of fourth degree (except $ax^4+bx^2+c=0$). Any other methods for solving the system?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore, thank you for the response! I would like a solution without guessing, though. Can I ask what do you mean by "due to symmetry"? What is symmetric in the system?

Comment: What on earth is with all of the downvotes on the answers here? Seems like someone is serially downvoting (of sorts)...

Comment: @CameronWilliams with you on that

Comment: I flagged for moderator attention since this is very negative behavior.

Comment: @CameronWilliams good,it is definetly intentional,because after 2 seconds or so after the answer being posted there is a downvote,I cant fathom the downvoter to read an anwer within 2 seconds unless the downvoter is a superhuman

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is actually a much, *much* neater method. Following your solutions, we subtract the equations (or substitute $20$) to get,
$$(u-v)+(v^2-u^2)=0$$
Using the familiar identity $a^2-b^2$ $=(a-b)(a+b)$,
$$-(v-u)+(v-u)(v+u)=0$$
which, on factoring, implies
$$(v-u)(-1+v+u)=0$$
which implies
$$v=u\text{ or }v=1-u$$
All that remains is mere substitutions into our original equations.

Hope this helps. Have a wonderful day. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Now this is  a good answer(upvoted with all force i could muster!)

Comment: Thank you all very much! +64 is a huge amount ;) (=

Comment: ultraedge you mean +65?

Comment: Someone downvoted! Plus some other reps from other posts.

Comment: But no one has downvoted *this* post

Comment: Probably the website counted the -1 from the downvote I gave earlier to a PhysicsSE post.

Comment: Oh i got it , i misread your comment as if someone dwonvoted your post ofcourse, thats where the -1 comes from

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Edited: thanks to several comments below, I find that the original answer made a (serious) mistake in counting the degrees of relevant polynomials and thus a mistaken use of the fundamental theorem of algebra. I apologize for the errors. A not-so-elegant way to fix the argument is added.</sup>

---

Systems of nonlinear equations are in general difficult; solutions are found by numerical methods.

Nevertheless, for this particular problem,
by inspection<sup>$\dagger$</sup>, there are at least four solutions:
$$
(-2,-2),\quad (-2,2),\quad (2,-2),\quad (2,2)\tag{1}
$$

We claim that the system has at *most* four solutions.

On the other hand, by symmetries, it suffices to show that $(2,2)$ is the *unique* solution in the first quadrant: any other solution not in (1) would give you one more solution in the first quadrant.

If you introduce the new variables $u=x^2$ and $v=y^2$:
$$
v=20-u^2,\quad u=20-v^2,\quad u,v>0
$$

The pair $(u,v)$ is the intersection of two parabolas on the $u$-$v$ plane.

If one draws a picture<sup>$\dagger\dagger$</sup>, one can see that one has only one intersection on the first quadrant, which implies that the first-quadrant solution to the original system is unique.

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup>Notes. The observation $20=4+16$ gives an obvious hint to get a solution.

<sup>$\dagger\dagger$</sup> Yes, this is just a hand-waving geometric "proof".

[image]

Comment: This downvote is undeserved.

Comment: [+1] from me. Thank you!

Comment: Can I ask you what do you mean by "the system can be reduced to a polynomial of degree four"? How can I do that?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra says us that the equation has at most four solutions IN $v$, and you only suggested TWO possible $v$'s, so there might be more (actually there are)

Comment: "...you get a polynomial of degree four": degree eight, surely? It is of degree four in $x^2$, but four solutions for $x^2$ means up to eight solutions for $x$. So I think this answer is wrong.

Comment: @TonyK: yes. That was a silly mistake. I edited my answer. Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @SeewooLee: that was certainly a mistake. Thank you very much for your comment. I edited the answer.

Comment: @IDoktorova: I made a mistake; I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

By substracting the two equations you get
$$ x^2(1-x^2) + y^2(y^2-1) = 0$$
$$ -(x^2-\frac12)^2 + (y^2-\frac12)^2 = 0 $$
so
$$ x^2 - \frac12 = \pm (y^2-\frac12) $$
that is
$$ x^2 = y^2 $$
or $$ x^2 = 1- y^2 $$
Analysing theses two cases it's easy to solve the equations.

Comment: I dont know who it is but there is one downvoter who is roaming here to downvote each and every post including the question!

Comment: Can you explain to me how do we get from the first to the second line?

Comment: @IDoktorova expand the second equation. It'll be clear from there. It's just a clever form of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can *guess* the answer, which might be $(u, v) = (2, 2)$. Since there might exist other solutions, we need to think more.

The next thing is: I believe that you can draw the graph of $u = 20 - v^{2}$ and $v = 20 -u^{2}$ on $(u, y)$-plane, which gives two parabolas that are reflections each other with respect to the line $u = v$. And, you have another guess: The other solutions do not satisfy $u\geq 0$ and $v\geq 0$, which should happen since $u = x^{2}$ and $v = y^{2}$. (Note that there are 3 more intersection points) So we can say confidently that the only solution is $(u, v) = (2, 2)$, but this is not a *proof*. There's another solution that you can guess that corresponds to another intersection point with $u = v$ other than $(4, 4)$. If you set $u = v$, then you obtain $u = -5, 4$ by solving a quadratic equation.

At last, to *prove* that this is the only solution, note that the degree 4 polynomial should be divisible by $(v-4)$ and $(v+5)$ since $4, -5$ are roots of it. We have
$$
v^{4} - 40v^{2} +v + 380 = (v-4)(v+5)(v^{2} - v - 19)
$$
and $v^{2} - v - 19  = 0 \Leftrightarrow v = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{77}}{2}$, where both of them fail to satisfy $(u \geq 0) \wedge (v \geq 0)$. So the only answer is $(u, v) = (2, 2) \Leftrightarrow (x, y) = (\pm 2, \pm 2)$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following problem: $$\begin{bmatrix}x^2+y^4=20\\ x^4+y^2=20\end{bmatrix}$$

In the first equation, you can isolate $x$ to get $x=\sqrt{20-y^4}$ and $\:x=-\sqrt{20-y^4}$. You then substitute the $x$ values into the second equation to get:
$$\left(\sqrt{20-y^4} \right)^4 +y^2=20, \left(-\sqrt{20-y^4} \right)^4 +y^2=20$$

Simplifying the equations will result in $y=2, y=-2$. You can then substitute the solution into the first equation and you will get $x=2,-2$ depending on which value of $y$ you substitute. Therefore, the final solutions are:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x=2,\:&y=2\\ x=-2,\:&y=2\\ x=2,\:&y=-2\\ x=-2,\:&y=-2\end{pmatrix}$$