# Solve $\begin{cases}u+(u+1)^2=20\\u^2+(u+1)=20\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

This question is related to [the previous question I posted today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4008153/solve-begincasesx2y4-20-x4y2-20-endcases). So I am trying to solve $$\begin{cases}u+(u+1)^2=20\\u^2+(u+1)=20\end{cases}.$$
The system is equivalent to $$\begin{cases}u^2+3u-19=0\\u^2+u-19=0\end{cases}.$$ We can actually solve the two equations for $u$ and see if they have common solution(s). But I tried to substract the the two equations to get $$2u=0\\ \Rightarrow u=0.$$ Actually $u=0$ isn't root to any of the equations. Is this a contradiction? What do we actually get when we substract the equations? (or when we substract 2 equations in general) What does this mean?

Comment: @mrsamy, what do you mean? The system that I am talking about is only with $u$ as a variable.

Comment: If we arrive at a contradiction, the system of equations have no solution.

Comment: I mean which previous question are you referring to?

Comment: @mrsamy, I am talking about the second case when $v=u+1$. Substituting into the original system gives:...

Comment: Where are the $u$ and $v$ from? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @mrsamy, please read my previous post. I have written where does $u$ and $v$ come from.

Comment: Your quoted previous question is about the system $x^2+y^4=20$ and $x^4+y^2=20$. I have no idea how you get the two equations about $u$ here.

Comment: That's really not the point. I think my question is clear even if we don't have the context. I just thought it would be fine if I wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the equations you immediately draw $u=u^2$, but neither $0$ nor $1$ are solutions of the system.

Substracting the equations does not introduce new solutions, but if you drop the other equations, you do.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: I mean, I saw that it were only 4 seconds you wrote the answer and it got downvoted, but I upvoted it :).

Comment: @LightYagami: I can accept downvotes, provided they are explained.

Comment: Yes, true, people don't explain why they downvote, maybe because there were already 5 answers written, so you didn't add anything useful (maybe).

Comment: If I understand, I should write $$\begin{cases}u^2+3u-19=0\\u^2+u-19=0\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}u=0\\u^2+3u-19=0\\u^2+u-19=0\end{cases}?$$

Comment: So I should combine the difference with the original equations, right?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, do I understand it right?

Comment: @IDoktorova: right, though the $\iff$ is vacuously true.

Comment: Can I ask you why?

Comment: @IDoktorova: because there are no solutions.

Comment: This is really the easiest explanation I have read from the answers here. Thank you! So when I add or substract equations, I should always consider the other equations, right?

Comment: @IDoktorova: whatever you do with the equations !

Comment: For example here I can write $$\begin{cases}2u+1=3\\u+1=3\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}u=0\\2u+1=3\\u+1=3\end{cases},$$ right?

Answer (score 2):

You've showed that the only possible solution to your system of equations is $u=0$. But $u=0$ is not in fact a solution. So there are no solutions.

Since this is a system of two equations in only one variable, you should not find this fact surprising! You'd have to get very lucky in order for the system to have any solutions.

Comment: Can you clarify for me why by substracting these 2 equations and getting $u=0$, this means only $0$ is a possible solution?

Comment: Essentially, taking the sum or difference of two equations is an operation that is always valid, but might "forget" some information about their solutions. That is, if $u$ is a solution to two equations, then $u$ must also be a solution to their difference — but if $u$ is a solution to the difference of two equations then $u$ need not be a solution to each equation individually. So your manipulations have shown that $u=0$ is the only possible option, but not that $u=0$ is an actual solution..

Answer (score 2):

Visually, here's what's happening:

$\hskip{3cm}$[image]

The red curve is $y=x+(x+1)^2$, and the green is $y=x^2+(x+1)$.

The curves do intersect, namely at $x=0$. But the value of $y$ at that point of intersection is not equal to $20$.

Answer (score 2):

If we introduce the variable $v$ and the constraint $v=u+1$, then the system of equations may be written as

\begin{align}u+v^2&=20\\u^2+v&=20\\ v-u&=1 \end{align}

Plotting these equations (below) we obtain two parabolas and a line. The parabolas happen to intersect in four points, none of which happen to land on the line. As such there's no solution to all three equations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By subtracting the two equations you  never used the fact they originally equaled $20$. You merely used the fact the expressions on LHS are equal, which is indeed true for $u=0$. The constant number on RHS got cancelled while subtracting...

Comment: I am not sure I understand why by subtracting the two equations I never used the fact they originally equaled $20$. I am substracting $u^2+3u-19=0$ and $u^2+u-19=0$, right?

Comment: @IDoktorova: Yes, you are. But In that process, did those equations included the information that they equalled $20$? No, right? So, the only information that was contained was that $u^2+3u-19$ and $u^2+u-19$ are equal, which is true for $u=0$.

Comment: @IDoktorova: If however, somehow you plugged the value of $u$ by solving one equation into the other equation, you would get no solutions directly, because now both things have been used... (one that $u^2+u-19$ and $u^2+3u-19$ are equal and also that they equal to $20$ simultaneousy.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Not a contradiction: not every system of equations has a solution.

Your calculation shows that **if** the system has a solution, then $u=0$. And since $u=0$ is not a solution, it follows that your system has *no* solution.

---

> But I tried to subtract the two equations to get...

When you do subtraction, you are *assuming* that there is a solution $u$ that satisfies both equations, which is not necessarily true.

Consider a much simpler example.

You try to solve
$$
2u+1=3,\quad u+1=3
$$

You can solve the two equations for $u$ to see if they have a common solution.

You can also subtract the second equation from the first one to get
$$
u=0
$$
which is not a solution to *both* equations.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain to me why by doing subtraction, I am assuming that there is a solution $u$?

Comment: @IDoktorova: you are welcome. When you "subtract" something from another you need to have two things in the first place. In the simpler example above, when you say subtract the equation $u+1=3$ from $2u+1=3$, you mean that there is a $u$ such that both equations *hold* in the first place; otherwise, you have nothing to do the subtraction. To give you another example, consider two equations: $u^2+1=0$ and $2u^2+1=0$. Both equations have no solution. But if you do subtractions, you get $u^2=0$ which has a solution.